# Extract the names after the keywords from a string

Tags: python

Here i m trying to pull out the names in a text after keyword matched

`Keywords = ['customer::name:', '- first name:', 'let me get you to a specialist. please tell us your first name', 'please tell us your first name']`

Here the name should be pulled out after if any of the keyword occurs in the string

The excel data is,

```
str1=
- Selections: U-verse TV > HSC - Inline Auth Uverse
Mindy has left the chat
You are being transferred, please hold...
Customer::Name: jhon henry

str2=
Adam has left the chat
You are being transferred, please hold...
- First Name: jennatee
tGuard Information >> Wireless Number: TG_NOT_FOUND *** Wireless BAN: TG_NOT_FOUND

str3=
Agent::[virtualAssistant.nina]: <div onclick="window.inqFrame.Application.sendVALinkClicked(event);" >Let me get you to a specialist. Please tell us your first name.</div> 
Customer::karl
Once the installation is done, you can expect to receive the e-mail notication regarding all the details.

str4=
Let me get you to a specialist.<br /><br /> Please tell us your first name.</div>  ***  Customer::Max canon  ***  Agent::[virtualAssistant.nina]: <div onclick="window.inqFrame.Application.sendVALinkClicked(even)
```

The output for each string should be like as follows,

for str1, [out]: Jhon henry.

for str2, [out]: jennatee.

for str3, [out]: karl.

for str4, [out]: Max canon.

I have tried in this way, but didn't worked out.
If my code is not relevant to get the output as i mentioned above, pls show me in another approach to solve this.

```
str=[str1,str2,str3]
m=re.search(r'[customer::name:|first name|let me get you to a specialist. please tell us your first name|please tell us your first name]', str)
m.groups()
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: Is it only looking for a limited set of identifiers (key names), or could there be any key name followed by a value? I noticed `Agent::[virtualAssistant.nina]` in `str3` for instance - so how would it know to avoid that? Specific targeted key names or the type of value, such as ignoring values enclosed in brackets?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
#this pattern gives the next word after the match. You can add more match strings if you like
pattern=r'((?<=)(customer::name:|customer::|first name:|please tell us your first name)(.?\w+))'

print (re.findall(pattern,str.lower(string))[0][2])
```